# Extension to append username and date to Visual Studio 2010 code comment

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there an Visual Studio 2010 extension that would allow you to insert comments and automatically append your username and current date:

```
// You type comments here [by Toni, on 03/26/2011]
```

It would help us to maintain uniform comments format in our solution.

**Edit**: This question is not about VCS, I am aware you can add and enforce comments there. I am just looking for Visual Studio 2010 Client only solutions!

Comment: I suppose that should be handled by VCS

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler, +1, absolutely, that's the responsibility of the version control. You should post your comment as answer. I will upvote it.

Comment: Well I am looking for something like a plugin, probably should rephrase my question. :(

Comment: @Toni Frankola, there is no need to rephrase. Your question is very clear, it's just what you are trying to achieve not a good thing. IMHO source code shouldn't be polluted with such information especially when it is already handled by the VCS you are using. Oh, you are using a VCS, aren't you?

Comment: @Darin, ok, you convinced me. Didn't want to post it as answer originally since it doesn't answer the question itself.

Comment: Who said I am using VCS? Maybe I just have code?

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler, of course that it answers the question. Showing what the best practice for something is not only that is answering the question but it is providing insight into how things should be done :-)

Comment: @Toni, now we will convince you to use VCS since there is no excuse not to use it.

Comment: @Toni Frankola, well, that's bad, what can I say? What if your hard disk crashes, you will be left without code :-) Quickly, pick a VCS before it's too late. I use a VCS even for my Word and Excel files, for source code I thought this was implicit :-) Writing source code without VCS could be considered as a crime during code reviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with snowbear that keeping track of who wrote what code belongs in source control.  If for whatever reason it makes more sense for your group to have the comments in the code, then you could probably get away with just creating a visual studio macro and tieing it up to a hotkey.  Something like the following should suffice:

```
Sub TaggedComment()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "//   [by "
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = Environment.UserName
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = ", on "
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "]"
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText)
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.CharRight(False, 3)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could look at creating a [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) instead (which seems to be the more performant solution).

Answer (score 10):

That should be handled by your version control system since it's more a code metadata than a code itself. Leaving it in code may lead to more troubles than taking from VCS in case if somebody will update a comment but will forget to update an author. Most modern VCS have `blame` command ([see SVN blame for example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html)) which will show the revision and author of that comment line.

Comment: Nice answer, precisely said, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [LogSubstPol](http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/) on codeplex?

I quote:

> LogSubstPol is a TFS check-in policy
>   which inserts the check-in comments
>   and other keywords into your source
>   code, so you can keep track of the
>   changes even if you are not connected
>   to TFS. It can be compared with the
>   $log$ (and other) substitition in any
>   other CVS systems.

Otherwise, you can write your own :-) It should be based on TFS checkin policy extensibility, using the [PolicyBase Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.policybase%28VS.80%29.aspx%29)

Comment: I am not looking for TFS plugin :(, not using TFS

Comment: @Toni - oh sorry, I missed that :-)